# Effect on Query to find range after calculation

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a View `V1` with a column `Name`, `DateOfBirth`.

In my stored proc,  I created a temporary table `T2` as given below.

```
MinAge MaxAge Category
0      5      Under 5
13     19     Teenager
```

My stored proc query goes:

```
Select V1.Name, T2.Category 
from V1, T2 
where DATEDIFF(hour,V1.DateOfBirth ,GETDATE())/8766 between T2.minage and T2.maxage
```

As of now my result set looks fine. My query is, since there is no direct relatioship between these two tables, going forward can my query result be effected in any way?

Comment: What's your question? are you looking for a better approach?

Comment: Please post the structure of the original tables, it may be easier to make this result set directly from those tables.

Comment: I am asking for accuracy of this approach. And if this is faulty, is any better way possible.

Comment: Personally, if I were creating the temporary table (rather than keeping a permanent table) rather than minAge and MaxAge, I'd have MinBirthDate and MaxBirthDate, calculated *ONCE* as GETDATE() - MaxAge and GETDATE() - MinAge.   Then you don't have to do DateDiff on each row, you just have v1.DateOfBirth between t2.MinBirthDate and t2.MaxBirthDate

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgre? Please retag your question to get better answers.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are using `/ 8766`. This will give inaccurate results (a year less) for the dates after the birthday until the end of the year.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović : Is there any better formula for date difference ? Please can you post so I can test and use.

Comment: My appologies, I didn't interpret correctly results of my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer, I am forced to assume that there would be no major effect. Though suggestion from @GregHNZ is quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to determine age by adding years to their date of birth than dividing by days or hours.  I'd add 5 years to their date of birth and compare that with getdate(), or your reporting date, to determine who was under/over 5 years old at that point in time.